# How to show and quit from unrecoverable error

Tags: android, error-handling

What do people recommend for exiting a program when, say, a 'try/catch' results in an error?

Some people suggested System.exit(1); but others say this causes instability, but I'm really not clear on what should be done easily. Lots of stuff about intents and jframes (not android?) stuff, but there should be an easy way to just stop.

And secondarily, what's the best way to do a message just before shutdown? Is there some kind of pop-up message capability, something like Toast, but that doesn't stay up very long, it'd be nice to have something that just works - no fussing around with intents and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in your activity, a toast should work fine.  As for cleanup, you can try to call finish() in your activity and/or stopself() from your service(s).  Could also use stopService() if appropriate.

Comment: The problem with toast is that it goes away after a few seconds. Is the 'Dialog' class what I want? And I have no services, would 'finish()' cleanly exit everything instead of System.exit()? Thanks!

Comment: @Paul You haven't really stated what you are trying to accomplish but if you are making a custom force close box, then a Dialog or AlertDialog may suit your purposes.  My understanding of finish() is that is does provide a cleaner exit than System.exit().  If you drink the GoogleAid, then you should never call, or need to call System.exit() [link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/6617757d17c70004/7d28a46ec9105626)